# Picture of a 4D knot

Tags: geometry, knot-theory

A knot is a way to put a circle into 3-space $S^1 \to \mathbb R^3$ and these are often visualized as 2D knot diagrams.

Can anyone show me a diagram of a nontrivial knotted sphere $S^2 \to \mathbb R^4$ (differentiable)?

Comment: does the klien bottle count? I don't think its one but I am not sure. if it is I would like a different one.

Comment: The Klein bottle does not count as a 'knotted sphere' - it's not a sphere in the first place!  (That is, there's no diffeomorphism $S^2\to K$, because any such would preserve orientation and while $S^2$ is orientable, $K$ isn't.)  It's arguably much closer to a torus than a sphere, anyway...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.knotplot.com/knot-theory/) or [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lIM9p6XOKo)?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a picture of a 4D knot. Most of the picture is embedded in a $3D$ time slice at time $t=0$. Then as you let $t$ increase the two top boundary circles persist, until you reach $t=1$ when they are capped with a disk. Similarly you cap off the two bottom boundary components with disks as $t$ decreases.

You can see that this construction yields a $2$-sphere since it represents two cylinders joined by a tube with caps added on the cylinder's ends.
[image]

Comment: Very nice picture!  I can see that this really is a picture of a 2-sphere, but what kind of invariants would be used to show this 2-sphere is actually knotted?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The fundamental group of the complement should do the trick, which you can compute using Seifert-van Kampen.

Answer (score 5):

The book *How Surfaces Intersect in Space* by J. Scott Carter covers this subject well, starting on page 226. You can get a free PDF of this book at http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/cartert.pdf . The book *Surfaces in 4-Space* by Carter, Kamata, and Saito covers this in-depth.

The premise of these books is that surfaces in 4-space can be represented as movies of embedded curves in 3-space, knotted or not.

If you want to see such a diagram Right Now®, then here is the first such diagram from *Surfaces in 4-Space*, the Fox-Milnor knotted sphere, which I am posting here FOR EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES ONLY, NOT FOR PROFIT:

[image]

Comment: Oh man, for the longest time I was staring at the transition from $t=3$ to $t=4$ and seeing nothing more than [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SpD.jpg). If anyone else is as confused as I was, all that's happening is that they take the two loops and just wind them around each other.

Comment: LOL! No, literally, I mean it.

Comment: +1 for the link. Carter's book looks very good.  I'm hooked at the preface: "Milnor's book _Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint_ is a model for clarity, conciseness, and rigor. The current text might be subtitled _Topology from Scott Carter's Viewpoint_, and critics will, no doubt, say it is a model for none of the above." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ralph Fox's "[A Quick Trip Through Knot Theory](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/QuickTrip.pdf)" [1] has a *lot* of examples in section 6.

1. In *Topology of 3-Manifolds and Related Topics*, M.K. Fort (ed.), 1962.