# A puzzle on knotted surfaces

Tags: geometry, puzzle, homotopy-theory, knot-theory

Only after having learned that the somehow only notion of [equivalence of knots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317043/equivalence-of-knots) is definitely "ambient isotopy" I stumbled over this blog entry on [ambient isotopy](http://blogs.helsinki.fi/kulikov/2010/07/07/ambient-isotopy/). (Had it been earlier!)

What bothers me since then are the two puzzles at the bottom of this page: I have no glue how to solve them.

One of the puzzles asks to show that the following two embeddings of the genus two surface are equivalent:

[image]

Can anybody give me a hint? Or - even better - is there a movie around that shows the equivalence? (Or cannot there be such a movie - for specific reasons?)

Comment: honestly you will just deprive yourself the fun of solving this.. just keep trying its possible, start at the RHS to get to the LHS.

Comment: Why not start at the LHS to get to the LHS? Is this essential ("psychologically")?

Comment: obviously if it can be done it can be done backwards, but it comes much easier if you start from the RHS.

Comment: My powers of imagination do not suffice, I'm afraid. Do you have another piece of assistance?

Comment: I couldn't resist thinking about the second one : http://i.stack.imgur.com/RKjvT.png  still feels like witchcraft, though.

Comment: @mercio: Great! (Do you possess witchcrafts?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: sorry]${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I appreciate that you hazard the consequences of being a spoiler! (And it still takes me some effort to digest your solution. It's not that easy than you might expect.)

Comment: To be honest: at first sight it looks like a "sleight of hand". I still cannot believe it.

Comment: @HansStricker, at least I can replace this with a problem that's [29x harder](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314131/picture-of-a-4d-knot)

Comment: @HansStricker, You need to have Plasticine/Clay/Blue-Tac in your hands to really see this happen.

Comment: I found it 29x harder than the usual ("simple") puzzles à la Thinking outside the box: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box

Comment: Next, I want to understand, what's really going on here. Can it be described maybe by something like Reidemeister moves for knotted surfaces?

Comment: I want to tell you how much I appreciate your sketches: they are at least as instructive as a fullblown movie! (For pedagogical reasons, one might drop the middle one...)

Comment: Believe it or (k)not: I am still stuck with the second puzzle. But this time, I will try even harder...

Comment: @HansStricker, The knotted spheres one? I don't expect you to solve it.. I've been toying with it for a long long time and haven't cracked it yet.

Comment: No, not the knotted spheres one! With the second puzzle (called **Puzzle 3**) on the web page I pointed to: http://blogs.helsinki.fi/kulikov/2010/07/07/ambient-isotopy/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7730/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-user58512)

Answer (score 3):

I am glad my blog entry was useful. I agree that this is a matter of spoiling, but behind this link you can find the solutions to both of the problems in my blog post: http://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/72327738/toporatk1.pdf?version=2&modificationDate=1322829341390&api=v2 it is in Finnish, but I hopefully assume that your image-reading-Finnish is ok ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vadim. And welcome to MSE!