# Untieable knotted surfaces

Tags: geometry, knot-theory

After [having seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/318239/1792) how - comparatively - easy it is to untie a *seemingly* knotted surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I am now looking for *really* (= untieable) knotted surfaces.

> Is there a most simple explicit example?

Comment: So if you just take a knot, say, a trefoil, and bulk it up a bit, is its surface not genuinely knotted?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give the obvious answer: Take a trefoil knot $K \subset R^3$.  Let $N$ be a regular neighborhood of $K$.  So $N$ is an embedded copy of the solid torus in $R^3$.  Now let $T = \partial N$ be the boundary of $N$.  So $T$ is a two-torus embedded in $R^3$.  This surface $T$ is "knotted" in the fashion you desire.  (At least, it is knotted on one side...)